# SQL calculations based on results previous rows - recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, lag, recursive-query

I'm trying to do a calculation within SQL which I'm struggling with.

Below is code to create the example that I am working with

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [AccountNo] bigint, [Month] int, 
[PaymentCycle] int, [OpeningBal] decimal(2,2), [Issue] decimal(13,2), 
[Collections] decimal(38,2), [Rebates] decimal(38,2), [ClosingBal] 
decimal(38,2) )

INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 1, 201703, 0, 0.00, 100.00, 0.00, 0.00, 100.00 ), 
( 1, 201704, 1, NULL, 0.00, -31.60, 0.00, NULL ), 
( 1, 201705, 2, NULL, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, NULL ), 
( 1, 201706, 3, NULL, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, NULL ), 
( 1, 201707, 4, NULL, 0.00, -60.00, 0.00, NULL ), 
( 1, 201708, 5, NULL, 0.00, -78.00, 0.00, NULL ), 
( 1, 201709, 6, NULL, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, NULL ), 
( 1, 201710, 7, NULL, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, NULL ), 
( 1, 201711, 8, NULL, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, NULL )
```

In this example I know what the values will be for the first row (Payment Cycle 0) and therefore can manually feed these in, for all of the subsequent rows I need to do 3 calculations.

1) OpeningBal - This is the LAG of the previous rows closing figure

2) Revenue - Calculated as the OpeningBal x 20%

3)  ClosingBal - This value is the sum of all components within the row so

```
OpeningBal + Revenue + Issue + Collections + Rebates
```

I am able to achieve this for Payment Cycle 1 using the LAG function however  I want to this to cycle through and store the previous closing balances in memory to use in the next cycle - I've read up on recursive CTE's but am struggling to implement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Nathan

Edit: Added desired result below

[image: Result Image]

Comment: could you post the expected result for this data?

Comment: Added desired result as an image. Apologies - I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: hi @a_horse_with_no_name, may be one with lot of brackets :-)